# How can i send email with html anchor link?

Tags: python, html, django, email

I tried this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('hello subject', '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/' + tempToken + '">Confirm</a>'
, 'from', ['to'], fail_silently=False)
```

But signing in email, I got a string like that:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/xxx">Confirm</a>
```

But i wanted a html anchor link: [Confirm](http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/xxx)

How can I send the message with html anchor link?

It will be very much appreciated if someone help me to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because by default the send_mail() method messages in plain text rather than HTML.
Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) on how to send HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Django only does plain text email by default. Check out [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2560/) for HTML email; there are many more [here](http://djangosnippets.org/tags/email/).